# Moderator elections: is display order of candidates randomized?

Tags: feature-request, moderator-election

I just voted for 3 candidates in the moderator elections.

The list was pretty long. As much as I wanted to read every candidate statement carefully and thoroughly, I got a bit tired as I descended down the list. I aborted the mission before reading all statements.

Then it hit me that candidates shown at the top have a much higher chance of being voted as top-choices.

I wonder if the order is randomized between visitors/voters to make the election more fair.

[Apologies if this was asked before. I searched and couldn't find anything on the subject]

Comment: If you can't be bothered to read all the options you should not be voting.

Comment: Did you actually refresh the page to see for yourself if this is actually done?

Comment: @csmckelvey As much as you'd like to hope that would be the case, the reality of the world that we live in is that people don't do that.  In most any election there's an advantage to having your name higher up on the ballet.  Rather than just hope that it stops being the case because people should know better, the responsible thing to do when running an election is to attempt to account for it as much as is feasible.

Comment: @servy - thanks for the tip.  The downvoting of an innocent, important, and honest question on a site that promotes the "Be nice" principle is disconcerting though.  I also have to disagree with csmcelvey.  I actually spent 20 minutes reading and thinking about candidates.  There's definitely a value (added information) to voting on a random subset of the whole. This is true for every practical election where there are many candidates.

Comment: @arielf Downvoting a bad post is not violating the be nice policy.  Being nice doesn't mean that you refuse to ever give criticism.  Being nice simply means that feedback on a post is expected to be professional.  If you want to ensure that your questions are upvoted, not downvoted, then be mindful of the help center's guidelines on asking questions, and make sure that your questions are high quality questions that merit upvotes.

Answer (score 8):

As @Servy had commented, if you refresh the page, the candidates' nominations are randomized. Therefore, the order of the candidates *is* random for every voter.